# Is there such a thing as a general "grocery shopping online" program/API?

Tags: api, ecommerce, shopping-cart, shopping

Even before the Corona/Wuhan thing, I was forced to shop online for food for years. I tried out numerous stores (in Europe) and their websites are all disastrous. As in, horribly broken and user-hostile to the point where I truly feel that it's a nightmarish chore each time I have to buy more groceries. I put it off for days every single time because it's such a horrible experience, even though I have streamlined it as far as possible.

It strikes me that, since they all appear to use some standardized, international web store, there may exist such a thing as a program or PHP library to automate logging in on their site, put items in the shopping cart and maybe even to finalize the order, in some way that isn't a user-hostile nightmare.

Basically, I want to code my own little thing where I simply enter numbers into fields and then press a button in my own control panel (which I have coded) and which then makes a standardized API call with my username and password to make the purchase.

I've already looked on their site and not found any "API" mentioned there, but I cannot imagine that rich people actually sit and use these websites the way they are designed. They must be using some kind of third-party, slick software which lets them easily order things in a professional/clean manner instead of the "consumer-oriented" interface that is their website.

I'm thinking something like "youtube-dl" (lets you download almost any video as a file by entering a URL) but for shopping food.

Comment: Obligatory [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/927/) - that's your answer - NO!!!! (and there never will be)